# Add sql translate to a criteriaBuilder JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, plsql, jpql

I have a need to incorporate a plsql `TRANSLATE(string1, string_to_replace, replacement_string)` function to my query.

I am using `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder` to build my query in my java.

What I want to do is to do a simmilar query than this in java with a `criteriaBuilder`:

```
select * from person t where UPPER(TRANSLATE(t.name,'áàâäÁÀÂÄéèêëÉÈÊËíìïîÍÌÏÎóòöőôÓÒÖŐÔúùûüűÚÙÛÜŰ','aaaaAAAAeeeeEEEEiiiiIIIIoooooOOOOOuuuuuUUUUU')) LIKE UPPER('%variable%')
```

The `('%variable%')` is my variable in java.

My problem is how do I build a similar query in jpql?

Right now I have :

```
Predicate pName = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.<String> get("name")), "%" + dtp.getName().trim().toUpperCase() + "%");
```

wich is the equivalent of :

```
select * from person t where upper(t.name) like upper('%variable%')
```

Is translate function supported in JPQL?
Is it doable?
Do I need a Gandalf like Wizard?

Comment: JPA 2.1 has "FUNCTION" where you can execute RDBMS-specific functions (such as TRANSLATE).

Comment: Unfortunatly, I use JPA 2.0, and I dont see 'FUNCTION'.

Comment: As I said, you need JPA 2.1 to "see FUNCTION", and if you can't then you have to use "NativeQuery" and lose datastore independence

Comment: yes you are right, but instead, I added a virtual column to my table which allowed me to do a translate fuctiuon. Thank you for your informations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method "function":

```
Expression<String> func = criteriaBuilder.function("translate", String.class, criteriaBuilder.upper(root.<String> get("name")),
                    criteriaBuilder.literal("áàâäÁÀÂÄéèêëÉÈÊËíìïîÍÌÏÎóòöőôÓÒÖŐÔúùûüűÚÙÛÜŰ"), criteriaBuilder.literal("aaaaAAAAeeeeEEEEiiiiIIIIoooooOOOOOuuuuuUUUUU"));

Predicate pName = criteriaBuilder.like(func, "%" + dtp.getName().trim().toUpperCase() + "%");
```

Comment: in my case I had to separate each and every character in criteriaBuilder.literal string with commas. I use Postgresql.